# How do I replace the value of the old strings with the new strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, xcode, string

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var newStr = str.split(" ");

  for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++ ){
    for( var j = 0; j < newStr[i].length; j++ ){
   if(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) < 78){

     String.fromCharCode(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) + 13);

   }
     else if(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) >= 78){
          String.fromCharCode(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) - 13);
          }
     }
  }
    return newStr;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

I am able to translate the original code into their actual words but i have trouble changing them to their proper words on the new string to finish. Can someone please help.

Comment: Calling `String.fromCharCode()` without doing something with the returned value is pointless.

Comment: I know that but i want to know what to do with the returned value so i can get an output of "FREE CODE CAMP"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!    
    var newStr = str.split(" ");   
    var alteredStr = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++ ){   
            for( var j = 0; j < newStr[i].length; j++ ){   
                if(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) < 78){

                    //String.fromCharCode(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) + 13);
                    alteredString = alteredString + (newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) + 13).toString();
                }   
                else if(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) >= 78){   
                    //String.fromCharCode(newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) - 13);   
                    alteredString = alteredString + (newStr[i].charCodeAt(j) - 13).toString();   
                }   
            }   
        }   
    return newStr;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: I am still having trouble cause it is saying alteredString isn't defined

Comment: Can you post how you're using it?

Comment: @Tony becuase `alteredString` wasn't defined in the code, only `alteredStr` was. Change `var alteredStr = "";` on line 3 to `var alteredString = "";`.